# Is there a way to log the number of times ANY installed app on my device has been launched?

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I want to use this info to determine the most frequently used apps on my device.

I am also interested in finding out if there is a way to determine how much time I have spent using each app on my device.

It seems this info might be accessible only on "jailbroken" devices.  I am hoping that is not the case.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't do that for all apps.

instead , if you want to know how much times your app has been launched , try this :

on the splachscreen of your app ( or the first activity launched) , try to increment a number , and save it on the `SharedPreferences` :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int counter = prefs.getInt("counter", -1);

if(counter == -1 ) {
   //first launch of the app, init the counter 
   counter = 1;
}
else {
  // increment the counter
  counter++;
}

// update the value of the counter 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("counter",counter);
editor.commit();

//then you can do what you want with your counter , send it to your back end via web service...etc
```

Comment: From the question I think he wants all apps, rather than just his own app.

Comment: , yeah i see . but i think he can't do it for all apps  , he doesn't have the permissions to do that . what de you think ?

Comment: I think as he says, you'd need a jailbroken device. Certainly for iOS each app is sandboxed so you've no way of accessing that information. I'm not as familiar with Android.